# Trying to understand C sizing better

Tags: c

First things first, the code works, but it didn't for a while, and I'm trying to understand why what I did fixes it.

So I have a function:

```
int array_size(const char **array) {
    int i = 0;

    while (array[i] != NULL) ++i;

    return i;
}
```

I also have this pointer which I started with one element and a call to a function which modifies local_mig:

```
int main(void) {
    char **local_mig = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 1);

    populate_local_mig(&local_mig);

    int size = array_size(local_mig); // 9
}
```

This function looks like this (note the comment on second to last line):

```
void populate_local_mig(char ***local_mig) {
    // ...above here reads a directory with 5 .sql files
    while ((directory = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        int d_name_len = strlen(directory->d_name);

        char *file_name = malloc(sizeof(char) * (d_name_len + 1));

        strcpy(file_name, (const char *)directory->d_name);

        size_t len = strlen(file_name);

        if (len > 4 && strcmp(file_name + len - 4, ".sql") == 0) {
            (*local_mig)[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));
            strcpy((*local_mig)[i], file_name);
            ++i;

            *local_mig = realloc(*local_mig, sizeof(char *) * (i + 1));
        }
    }

    //(*local_mig)[i] = NULL;
}
```

Still with me? Good.

Later on, I call `array_size(local_mig);` and it returns 9. What the? I was expecting 5. So naturally when I iterate over `local_mig` later, I eventually segfault when it tries to read the 6th element.

So, I added `(*local_mig)[i] = NULL;` and suddenly everything was ok and it returned 5, like it should have.

All along I figured since I allocated exactly enough space to fit each character array, that the size would obviously be the number of times I resized `local_mig`.

Turns out I was wrong... very very wrong. But why, I ask...

Comment: `while (array[i] != NULL) ++i;` loops until it finds a pointer that has been set to `NULL`. When you include a line that sets the last pointer to NULL, this works correctly. When you take that line out, obviously it doesnt.

Comment: Un-commenting that line for sure fixes it, I just am not sure why.

Comment: Why do you expect `while (array[i] != NULL)` to stop if you did not set `array[i]` to `NULL` ?

Comment: I thought because I only allocated 5 (char *) to local_mig that there would be nothing past 5.

Comment: @brian You can only safely iterate `while (array[i] != NULL)` if you allocate with `calloc` (which initialized all pointers to NULL) or you manually initialize to `NULL` after using `malloc`. That way, only the pointers you have assigned will be not `NULL`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `calloc` does not necessarily initialize all pointers to NULL.

Comment: @M.M I'm fairly sure that `calloc` initializes all bits to 0 when the memory is allocated.  At least, that's what that documentation says?

Comment: @M.M That is a fair statement. It only initializes the pointers you are allocating, not pointers at other levels of pointer indirection if I understand what you are saying.

Comment: @LukePark yes, but all-bits-zero might not be a null pointer.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin no, I'm saying that after `int *x = calloc(sizeof(int), 1);`, then `x` might not be a null pointer, if you are on a system where all-bits-zero is not a null pointer.

Comment: @M.M I see what you are saying, and yes that is fair and something I did not consider in the comment.

Comment: @M.M Does such a system exist or are you talking in practice?  This seems like a negligible scenario...

Comment: @LukePark luckily that question is in the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html)

Comment: @M.M Well I learnt something today.  I think it's probably safe to assume that the OP isn't programming for the Prime 50 series though :L

Comment: @LukePark Right.  I think it makes some sense to use an address outside of any viable address space as a null pointer, especially on systems where address zero is a real memory location (yes I have used such a system!) but in practice probably nobody will do it because there's too much code out there which assumes calloc generated null pointers.

Comment: the posted code has a few critical logic errors.  Suggest googling for "three star programmer".   The value returned from malloc, although being set into a `**` pointer variable, is actually only `*`  The malloc and setting of the pointers in the array is what makes it a `**`.   Therefore, taking the address of the variable, to pass as a parameter does not make it a `***`.    multiplying by `sizeof(char)` has no effect and just clutters the code.  multiplying by 1 has no effect and just clutters the code. on the initial malloc, set the allocated memory to NULL, so works on all cases

Comment: Suggest searching stackoverflow.com for examples of how to generate a linked list.   The methods of doing so apply directly to your code.

Comment: @user3629249 It was the only way I knew to do it by reference. Would it make it better if I changed `populate_local_mig` to accept a `char **`, pass the value of `local_mig` to it, and return the value of `local_mig` back?

Comment: you might want to read/understand the answers for this question: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33525014/linked-list-issue-in-c>  for why/how to properly  insert into a linked list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't set the last pointer in your list to NULL, you will encounter undefined behavior in your `array_size` function, as it rolls right past the end of the array (with no marker to stop it) and into memory that you probably do not own and is not initialized.

The unpredicted size of `9` is the result of the aforementioned undefined behavior. It's probably the result of whatever was in memory at the time. Really, though, with UB, anything can happen.

Comment: It's a char** when it's called, but a char*** in the function. Does that matter?

Comment: There's two different variables both called `local_mig`.  It would indeed be clearer to use a different name for the `char ***` one.

Comment: `char**` and `char***` are two completely different types.  Would you pass an `int` where a `float*` was expected?  No.

Comment: @LukePark Right, of course not. I'm calling array_size on the char** version though. I have warnings cranked up, but there are no warnings. I'm fairly certain I'm not passing a char*** into a char**.

Comment: @owacoder I'm not calling it within `populate_local_mig`, I'm calling it later in main().

Comment: @owacoder You definitely helped me understand. Thanks. Where did the `9` come from from though?

Comment: Perfect, now you've fully answered my question. Up until now, I've been trying to figure out what + what = 9 in my code, when it reality, it's UB. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

The loop in `array_size` eventually gets up to testing `array[i] != NULL`, where `i` is the last index in the space you allocated with `realloc`.

If you actually did set this entry to `NULL` then all is well. But if you didn't:  uninitialized values are different to null pointers.  Reading an uninitialized value may cause a crash, or the compiler may optimize the program based on the assumption that you never read uninitialized values because the language specification says you aren't meant to do that!

A likely result is that this last entry will appear to contain a junk value which probably does not match `NULL`.  And then your loop continues to read past the end of the allocated space , with unpredictable results.