# Linked list issue in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I have to generate random numbers and put them in a linked list sorted. my code runs fine on my home computer on cygwin, however when I run it on the schools system, i keep getting that the list is empty. Not sure what the issue is.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int num;
    struct node *next;
}node_t;

node_t* insertNodeSorted(node_t *head, int x);
void printList(node_t *head);
void deleteList(node_t *head);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    node_t *dummy;
    int counter = 1;
    int a;

    if(argc != 4)
    {
            printf("Error. Exiting program...");
            exit(1);
    }//end if

    //seed random number
    srandom(atoi(argv[1]));
    dummy = NULL;

    while(counter < atoi(argv[2]))
    {
            a = random() % (atoi(argv[3]) + 1);

            printf("%d " ,a);

            insertNodeSorted(dummy, a);

            counter++;
    }//end while

    printf("\n\n");
    printList(dummy);

    deleteList(dummy);

    return 0;



 }

 node_t* insertNodeSorted(node_t *head, int x)
 {
    if(head == NULL)
    {
            head = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
            if(head == NULL)
            {
                    printf("Failed to create head node");
                    return head;
            }//end if
    head->num = x;
    head->next = NULL;
    return head;
    }//end if

    node_t *p;

    p = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if(p == NULL)
    {
            printf("Failed to create a new node.");
            return p;
    }//end if

    p->num = x;
    p->next = NULL;

    if(x < head->num)
    {
            p->next = head;
            return p;
    }//end if

    node_t *q, *r;
    q = head;
    while(q != NULL && q->num <= x)
    {
            r = q;
            q = q->next;
    }//end while
    p->next = q;
    r->next = p;

 }

 void printList(node_t *head)
 {
    node_t *p;

    if(head == NULL)
    {
            printf("List is empty");
            exit(1);
    }//end if

    p = head->next;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
            printf("%d ",p->num);
            p = p->next;
    }//end while
 }

 void deleteList(node_t *head)
 {
    node_t *p;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
            p = head->next;
            free(head);
            head = p;
    }//end while
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the args given? Also, does the school use the same platform as you at home, and did you take the executable to the school or did you compile it there. Were you able to debug?

Comment: @MrLister What is CS?

Comment: @MrLister In your context.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Wait, you mean my profile. C#, or C Sharp.

Comment: the program should be run like ./program_name 262262 50 1000

Comment: Also, i dont know what platform the school uses. It is just an unix system that is all i know.

Answer (score 3):

Your function

1. has undefined behaviour because in some cases it returns nothing and
2. in the main you did not reassign the head `dummy`. So it is not
   changed.

The function can look the following way

```
 node_t* insertNodeSorted( node_t **head, int x )
 {
    node_t *p = ( node_t * )malloc( sizeof( node_t ) );

    if ( p == NULL )
    {
            printf( "Failed to create a new node.\n" );
    }//end if

    else
    {  
        p->num = x;

        if ( *head == NULL || x < ( *head )->num )
        {
            p->next = *head;
            *head = p;
        }
        else
        {
            node_t *current = *head;
            while ( current->next != NULL && !( x < current->next->num ) )
            {
                current = current->next;
            }

            p->next = current->next;
            current->next = p;
        }
    }

    return p;  
}
```

And the function must be called like

```
insertNodeSorted( &dummy, a );
```

Comment: Having a little trouble understanding your code. For the parameter, why is there two stars?

Comment: @JohnDoe To change an argument you have to pass it by reference to a function. Otherwise function parameters are its local variables that initialized by copies of the values of arguments.

Comment: @JohnDoe  Consider for example void f( int *x ) { *x = 10; } int main( void ) { int x; f( &x ); printf( "%d\n", x ); }

Comment: Okay, I get the example. Just to make sure though. (**head ) means I am passing a pointer to the pointer named head?

Comment: @JohnDoe Yes. In the function the head can be changed for example when  it is initially equal to NULL or an element is inserted before it. So you have to pass it to the function by reference. Otherwise the function will deal with a copy of the head and the original head will not be changed.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's homework I will not give you the full answer.... but look at what is going on with main's dummy, and the local value of head inside insertNodeSorted.

If you are just using gcc and no debugger... add more printfs it'll help a ton...